# How to disable right-click in the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, html5-video

I have a WordPress website I would like to disable right-click in my iframe videos?

Comment: Depends on your code setup... For example does the iFrame have an ID or Name for access via code? Can you show a simple demo page of example iframe (send link)? The demo page can be deleted later if/when you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The oncontextmenu attribute should help you

```
<source src="yourvideo.ogg" oncontextmenu="return false;">
```